# No sound on remote machine

Tags: windows, audio, vpn, remote-desktop, sound-card

I connect to windows 8 desktop from windows 7 via vpn. There was a sound before but couple days ago it disappeared. The connection is bad but it still worked in the past. I put "Play on this computer" option in remote desktop connection application. How could I solve this problem?

Comment: If you are behind the remote pc physically, does it play sound then? It is likely that there's a problem on the remote pc that prevents (or mutes?) the sound. For example, some soundcards will automatically mute the audio if no speaker is connected via cable.

Comment: It looks like that everything fine on the remote pc. It's far away but the person who works there told me sound is okay. When I use control-panel sound and test remote device I don't hear anything despite of the device is enable and show wavering.

Comment: We've had this before (not using a VPN and RDP) but we've noticed that even though the audio bar is jumping around there was still no audio... the fix was to right click the volume icon (Win 8) and configure the default audio output device... this may give some clues to a fix for your scenario? No idea why it would stop, but our situation was the same, worked then didn't...